# Open a file (not .txt) with notepad++ and replace a line with string

Tags: python, subprocess, notepad++

I'm trying to open a file, needs to be with notepad++, and replace a certain line and position with a string

I saw some examples using the open function with readlines,write,append,replace,... but the normal notepad mess my file, below the code that i wrote to exemplify

```
import subprocess

mac = "F5:FF:60:60:10:FF"  #example

test = subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe", r"C:\Users\mypc\Project\test.axp"])
test.replace[5][10:27](mac)       #replace with mac in lane 5 and position 10 to 27
test.close()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What you have right now is nonsensical; that's no way to control Notepad++. I really think you should use the `open()` function and do the replacement in Python. "The normal notepad mess up my file" also doesn't factor in here - Python doesn't care about your normal notepad.

Comment: I think your issue is opening a `.axp` file. What does an `.axp` file look like when opened in the normal notepad? Please copy/paste the first couple lines of the result here~

Comment: i know it doesnt work like i wrote, just a example of the idea,  I need to edit the mac adress at line 190  to print the label , file open using notepad ----> Eau Claire WI                 € 7   ¼ÿÿÿó   ©ÿÿÿ                    ÿÿÿ        ÿÿ          
  MAC: F0:F2:60:30:00:AA 123455 C:\Program Files (x86)\\Samples\serial.txt Text6                    ïÿÿÿ                  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

Comment: What *is* the `test.axp` file? A Table? An Audio Compilation File?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `.axp` might be an `xml` formatted file. This could be confirmed if this prints out anything sensible.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('test.axp', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'xml')
print(soup)
```

`pip install beautifulsoup4 lxml`